# What should be checked after an Oracle migration

Tags: oracle, migration

After a large data migration, what needs to be checked to be confident that the data move has succeeded?

- the number of tables and rows in each schema is the same.
- the text data in the tables has not been corrupted. This is important if non alphanumeric characters (such as double byte) are used.
- the dumps or other files that have been been transferred have the same checksum.

Is there anything else that can be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to migrate the data between different versions of Oracle?

1. Generally, you can also look at your environmental parameter settings (init.ora parms) and your optimizer statistics after doing data migration.
2. See also Oracle tips for migration [click here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_10g_migration_tips.htm)